# how to add css for div tag

Tags: html, css

I have clock in one div tag and address in another div tag.
I want to display clock in left side and address on right side.Now address is displayed below the clock.

```
<div class="new">
   <div class="clock">
    //my clock code
   </div>       //end of clock div
   <div class="address">
      <p> </p> //address 
   </div>       //end of address div
</div>          //end of new div

css
  .new .clock{
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 0px 0 0;
    float:left;
   }
  .address{
   margin:0;
   padding:30px 0px 50px 0px;
   text-align:right;
   }
```

Comment: Float the address div right - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/54pqbh2e/ 2/

Comment: Or just use spans if you want inline elements anyway ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for clock: `float: left;`

for adress: `float: right;`

but if the browser window gets too small they will appear under each other again

Answer (score 1):

just add a float: left to the address as well.

Looks a bit wierd with the padding however

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code

```
.clock {
display:inline-block;
width:40%;
```

}

```
.address {
    display:inline-block;
    width:40%;
}
```

You can similary use float but you need to give the parent element a style like

```
.clock {
    float:left;
}

.address {
   float:right;
}
```

`.new{
clear:both;
}`

Answer (score 1):

I created a quick fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/imelgrat/ag19xhy1/) to show an example of how to place 2 divs side-by-side.

Here's the CSS code for it. I added a float property to each div and made them to have 40% of the total page width (can be higher as long as they don't add up to over 100%).

```
.clock {
      margin:0;
      padding:10px 0px 0 0;
      float:left;
      width:40%;
  }
  .address {
      margin:0;
      padding:10px 0px 0 0;
      text-align:right;
      float:right;
      width:40%;
  }
```